# Suitable static DataStructure that is required to be thread safe in an ASP.net Application for concurrent access from various web clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, design-patterns

Desired Workflow

1. First I wish to fetch a particular set of questions and answers from a huge set of questions and answers stored in SQL Server (tables tblQuestions and tblAnswers)
2. Fetched questions and corresponding answers will get stored in a static collection (either `List<Quiz>` or `hashmap<key,value>` where key will be quiz Id and value will be collections of Qns and Ans
3. For each http request I have to serve a particular question and its answers on the basis of a unique QuestionId.
4. Since many students will sit in exam for same quiz then I need not to fetch the same quiz set from DB repetitively, but if some other student of another stream starts his/her quiz then I need to fetch the quiz for him from DB and store it on the server's same static collection

**5. A set of quiz will be removed from the static collection once the quiz is over or turned off by administrator.**

So basically I want to know what will be the suitable database structure. I wish to remain with singleton pattern, and also wish to make it thread safe either through locks or any other mechanism

Example Model of Quiz

```
class Quiz
{
   int QuizId; //QuizId
   string QuizTitle; // Example - C# Quiz
   List<QuestionAns> qnsAns; // List of Questiona and answers related to this Quiz
}

class QuestionAns
{

   int QuestionId; //unique QuestionId
   string Question; // Question Text
   List<Answers> answers; //answers to this question ( can be more than one)
}

class Answer
{
   int AnswerId; //unique AnswerId
   string Answer;//Answer Text
   bool isRight;//Is this Answer right
}
```

Now I actually want to create a thread safe list of Quiz like **`List<Quiz>`**

How to do this or is there any other much suitable mechanism? I am not having very good knowledge of web application specific data structures.

One possible alternative to such data structure can be following

```
public sealed class Singleton
 {
     private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
         new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

     public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
     {
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have two options:

1.Either synchronize the access to the collection manually using locks (and perhaps a wrapper class):

> ```
> public class ThreadSafeList
> {
>     private List<Quiz> list = new List<Quiz>();
>     private object locker = new object();
>
>     private static ThreadSafeList instance = new ThreadSafeList();
>
>     private ThreadSafeList() { }
>
>     public static GetInstance()
>     {
>         return instance;
>     }
>
>     public void Add(Quiz q)
>     {
>         lock(locker) list.Add(q);
>     }
>
>     // whatever else you need to synchronize
> }
> ```

2.Or you can use some of the newer C# thread-safe collections, like [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx).

Comment: Yes I also thought about this ConcurrentBag collection , but actually I m not aware by the efficiency of this collection and also I want to know that whether or not I am making my workflow very typical. I mean to say is thread safety really a problem in this type of problem

Comment: yes Tudor locking in this way can be one of the good option I think

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta: As you said in your exposition, there is a possibility that several `Quiz` objects will need to be added the list concurrently. In this case you will need to synchronize the access.

Comment: so the object of this ThreadSafeList is also required to be static

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta: You can make this class into a singleton, yes. I can update the code with singleton semantics if you need.

Comment: yes pls update if possible. Moreover I found Jon skeet's C# singleton pattern much closer to ur suggestion http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: so in this collection if I m updating the collection and also deleting some item from collection than Is the lock required?  Anyways thanks a lot for your suggestion and efforts

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta: Yes, adding and deleting both need to lock the list in order to avoid inconsistencies in case of concurrent modifications.

Comment: thanks @Tudor , I will mark your answer as answered , I am just waiting for couple of more approaches if suggested by some one else. So here I am required to make the object like this                    private static ThreadSafeList myThreadsafeQuizRepository = new ThreadSafeList
();

Answer (score 1):

I find Lazy`<List<T>> Questions = new Lazy<List<Questions>>(() =>  { //Instantiation code here })` to be a good way to keep the logic simple and clear.